# connection refused when running terraform apply for GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, provisioning, google-iam

## 1. Error Description

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/google-cloud-platform-build?in=terraform/gcp-get-started) to setup Terraform for the GCP. However, when I run `terraform apply`, I get the following error message:

```sh
│ Error: Error creating Network: Post https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/css-assignment-2-3/global/networks?alt=json: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token: dial tcp: lookup oauth2.googleapis.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:32834->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
│ 
│   with google_compute_network.vpc_network,
│   on main.tf line 16, in resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network":
│   16: resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
```

### 1.1 Configuration

My `main.tf` configuration file for terraform looks like this:

```json
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = file("<path-to-key>.json")

  project = "<project-id>"
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name = "terraform-network"
}
```

### 1.2 Authentication

I double checked that the path to the key file and the project ID are correct. I also tried setting the variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point towards the key file which just results in the same error message.

The key was retrieved, following the tutorial mentioned above, by creating a service account and giving it the Project -> Editor role.

I only found [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922290/terraform-gcp-connect-connection-refused), somewhat related to my problem. However, the error message is a different one. When following the suggested steps (which basically are the same as in the tutorial), the error persists.

### 1.3 IPv6

As it seems to be a problem with my IPv6 configuration ([John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley)), here are some further information regarding this topic.

`ip link show dev wlan0` confirms that my network interface is up and running:

```sh
5: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:00:25:23:ce:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`ip -6 route` returns `::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium`. Is it right that `::1` means that the IP address could not get resolved which falls back to a wrong configuration of my [routing table](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration#Routing_table)?

I use `iwd` as my Wifi network manager. This is my `/etc/iwd/main.conf`:

```
[General]
EnableNetworkConfiguration=true

[Network]
EnableIPv6=false
NameResolvingService=systemd
```

Setting `EnableIPv6` in the `/etc/iwd/main.conf` to `true` or `false` does not change the error message.

## 2. Summary of Questions

- Any suggestions on what the source of this authentication problem might be?

  - Seems to be related to IPv6 ([John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley))
- Why do I get an IPv6 error when it should be disabled by default for `iwd`? ([source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd#Enable_built-in_network_configuration))

Comment: The problem is with your computer. The error message means that a connection to your IPv6 localhost [::1] for DNS resolution is being refused. Double-check your TCP/IP stack configuration and the DNS settings.

Comment: Hi, can you propose a way of how I could verify my configurations? `ip route show` returns: `default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 305 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.101`. `ip -6 route` returns `::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium`. However, I'm not sure about how to handle the further debugging. I enabled IPv6 in my `/etc//iwd/main.conf`, according to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd#IPv6_support) wiki entry. I also set `EnableNetworkConfiguration=true`, because I think that my IPv6 address is not getting resolved

Comment: I recommend that you disable IPv6 as a test. Reboot your system. The retry Terraform. Note: your IPv6 configuration does not look correct. You do not have a link-local address nor a default route. Packets sent via IPv6 will blackhole.

Comment: If the error message did not change after disabling IPv6, then you did not correctly disable IPv6 OR your TCP/IP configuration for DNS is incorrect. I recommend deleting this question and recreate another to get your network configured correctly.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking further into configuring IPv6 (the error message changed after disabling it, but it is still related to IPv6). Can you recommend a best practice for this? E.g. deleting this question completely and open another one without referencing Terraform at all or opening up a new one to get my network configuration right where I describe both Terraform error messages so future users with the same errors can find a proper solution or continuing this question with the new error message and dealing with the IPv6 setup in another, separate question?